# WebM Encoded file plays in Chrome but not FFv6 HTML5-Video

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ffmpeg, html5-video, vlc

I'm trying to use the new fancy html5 video player element and I was wondering:
I encoded a high resolution .mov container in VLC v1.1.9 to WebM format (although an FFMPEG command line would be extremely valuable if you have one handy) and it plays just fine in Chrome, but it won't open in Firefox. Would anyone have any ideas or in what direction I should be looking?

Comment: What MIME type are you sending for the video?

Comment: We really need to see how the video is being sent to the browser.

Comment: For encoding WebM using ffmpeg, see: http://blog.pcode.nl/2010/10/17/encoding-webm-using-ffmpeg/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the fix was to change the apache server config to associate *.webm files with the video/webm mime type.  This was done by creating a .htaccess file, or could be done in the apache mime types config.